# npm install from tfs feed (on build process) give error: Unable to authenticate

Tags: npm, tfs, azure-devops, npm-install, npm-package

We have our own npm package and a project that uses it,
I want to publish it to a tfs feed - repository and install it from there instead of from a physical file.

I published the package to the feed from my development machine,
and I changed the reference within the project that consumes it.

The whole process works fine from my machine, but when I try to consume the package on a build process in the tfs - it fails with the error :

> Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.

I've created `.npmrc` file at the project level with the registry address, and another file with credentials on the user directory,   and I did the same on the TFS machine.

What can cause the npm install (from my feed) to not work on the tfs machine?

**EDIT:**
When I add prefix @my to the registry at the user-level .npmrc file - like this:

```
@my:registry=https://my-feed-address
```

The error changes to:
"No valid versions available for my-package"

Comment: The build agent run with user, give to this user permissions in the feed.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, Do you mean Feed settings->Permissions ? If so, this user has owner permission.

Comment: Can you share your build pipeline?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I do not think that's the point,
Because even when I run the npm install command in the tfs server - in the project folder within the relevant 's' folder - I get the same behavior. + I edited my question.

Comment: Which version of TFS is it? Are you using the npm install task? it has and authentication section that you can point to your .npmrc file.  There is also a npm authenticate task you might want to run first.

Comment: @Etienne, It was the 2017 version, and we upgraded it to the 2019 version to solve this problem but it did not help. I tried both the `'Registries in my .npmrc'` option and the `'Registry I select here'` option, with\without selection of a `Service connection` which I created that connects to my feed. 
But, as I wrote in the previous comment, why it would work if running this command **inside the tfs server** in command line - it does not work? (I do not know why) I get the same error.

Comment: why do you think running it inside tfs server should skip auth?

Comment: Try adding a variable system.debug with a value of true you’ll get more information in the failure. That might help pinpoint the problem

Comment: @4c74356b41, When I run it inside the server - it should use the configuration an auth token listed in the npmrc file on the server, and it should succeed as it does from my machine, but it fails...

Comment: @Etienne, Is system.debug a variable of the process in tfs? What I need is details from the **npm**.

Comment: why do you think it should do that? also, can you verify the token is working? did you hardcode it?

Comment: @4c74356b41, The process runs in this machine. If not from this file - where should it take the settings? How can I verify the token is working? And what do you mean by _did you hardcode it_?

Comment: @banana by adding system.debug value of true, you'll get more info in the task log as to why npm authenticate doesn't work.

Comment: @Etienne, But it will not give me more details than running the `npm install` command inside the tfs server in Command Line, is not it?

Comment: It might give you the variables it uses and sometimes other errors

Answer (score 8):

1. Install this in machine: `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth`
2. Run this (in the directory where npmrc file is):
   `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`

Comment: i had the same problem but this solved in my case. in my build pipeline everytime before the restore i execute this vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc.  it works directly in build machine (without build process)? have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Create a file `.npmrc` in your project folder and add the following

```
registry=Your URL
always-auth=true
```

In the command prompt run both of these commands

`npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false`

`vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`

Comment: That's only works on Windows according to DevOps' documentation.

Comment: Does NOT work for ubuntu: `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`... possibly this is only for Windows OS

Comment: For Windows this did it for me.... You have to enable the script polycies (e.g. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` Yes )